# How to add each entries of multiple pandas dataframes. Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to take a new set of values in dataframe and add it to an existing one. But the addition I want is a 1 to 1. So the first entry in the dataframe adds to its respective entry in  the 2nd dataframe, and so on. I can easily do this if I was using numpy, but with pandas, this is been quite difficult. I'm also trying to take these different dataframes and calculate the median of each respective entries. Below is what I did for numpy, to get an idea of what I'm talking about:

```
import random 
import numpy as np


index = 10
Value_sums = np.zeros(index)

Vals = []

values1 = random.sample(range(100), 10)

values2 = random.sample(range(100), 10)

Value_sums = Value_sums + values1

Value_sums = Value_sums + values2

vals.append(values1)

vals.append(values2)

Out[54]: array([71., 82., 87., 59., 97., 99., 69., 50., 80., 61.])
```

The expected outcome for this part is to add each individual element together, and generate another array of the same size.

```
vals_stacked = np.stack(vals)

Out[49]: 
[[45, 36, 20, 63, 43, 10, 38, 79, 31, 67],
 [71, 82, 87, 59, 97, 99, 69, 50, 80, 61]]

vals_median = np.nanmedian(vals_stacked, axis = 0)

Out[53]: array([58. , 59. , 53.5, 61. , 70. , 54.5, 53.5, 64.5, 55.5, 64. ])
```

For the median, I stacked up all the different arrays I have and took the median of the first elements, and then the second and so on, to generate another array of the same size, but the entries are the median.

My dataframe looks something like this.

```
ts[0:10]
Out[51]: 
2011-10-06 03:54:44    45427
2011-10-06 03:55:01    45742
2011-10-06 03:55:15    45844
2011-10-06 03:55:29    45800
2011-10-06 03:55:43    46023
2011-10-06 03:55:56    46484
2011-10-06 03:56:10    46966
2011-10-06 03:56:23    47768
2011-10-06 03:56:37    48286
2011-10-06 03:56:50    48205
dtype: int32
```

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: What is your expected output? what have you tried in pandas that is not working? It seems pretty easy to do `df.median()`

Comment: I updated the post to include the expected result. I did try df.median() but that seems to only take the median of the value of the specified dataframe, and not the median of each element of multiple dataframes

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. It's much easier to just convert the dataframe into numpy, and do the same exact thing I did above.

```
values = ts.value
```